# Opening a sheet on 10.9

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In one of my controllers I'd like to open a modal sheet on 10.9.

This is the implementation code for the first controller:

```
#import "ABSAdvancedPreferencesViewController.h"
#import "ABSUnsyncableWindowController.h"

@interface ABSAdvancedPreferencesViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) ABSUnsyncableWindowController *unsyncableWindowController;
@end

@implementation ABSAdvancedPreferencesViewController

- (id)init {
  return [super initWithNibName:@"ABSAdvancedPreferencesViewController" bundle:nil];
}

- (IBAction)showUnsyncableSheet:(id)sender {
  if (self.unsyncableWindowController == nil) {
    self.unsyncableWindowController = [ABSUnsyncableWindowController new];
  }
  [self.view.window beginSheet:[self.unsyncableWindowController window] completionHandler:^(NSModalResponse returnCode) {
    CLS_LOG(@"Table dismissed");
  }];
}
```

When I execute the linked `IBAction` nothing happens. The `NSWindowController` subclass that should should show the modal has a XIB, Visible at launch is deactivated and `window` is already an outlet.

Debugging I saw that the `window` parameter is `nil` here, presumably because I call `new` in the previous controller:

```
@implementation ABSUnsyncableWindowController

- (id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow *)window {
  self = [super initWithWindow:window];
  if (self) {
    // Initialization code here.
  }
  return self;
}
```

Is there something else that I can check to show the modal sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `ABSAdvancedPreferencesViewController` `init`method is missing assigning the super result to self. Also, why don't you alloc/init the sheet controller as expected?

```
self.unsyncableWindowController = [[ABSUnsyncableWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"XIBNAME"];
```

That should alloc the window controller and you should be able to access its window for display.